# Can't uninstall or disable nginx

Tags: debian, systemd, nginx

Apparently I removed nginx but it keep starting at boot, I'm using lighttpd but nginx starts first causing lighttpd to fail to start, so at every boot I have to stop nginx and start lighttpd manually.

Things that I have done: ( `command`:  output )

- `apt-get remove nginx`: Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed
- `service nginx status`: [...] Active: active (running) [...]
- `update-rc.d nginx remove`
- `chkconfig nginx`: (nginx  off)
- `mv /etc/init.d/nginx /tmp/`
- `sysv-rc-conf`: (It is disabled at every runlevel)
- `rcconf`: (nginx is not listed)
- ... and many `reboot`

**System:** RPi 3B running Raspbian 8 (Jessie)

**EDIT**:

`dpkg -l  | awk ' { print $2 } '  | grep ^nginx` output:

```
nginx-common
nginx-full
```

Comment: dpkg-query: package 'nginx' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Comment: About the close vote: there are a lot of old documentation around, and still more users bound to think something is wrong with their systems with the changes of nginx from one to multiple packages, and with the migration to systemd; this post might be useful to future readers - the automatic moderation system is also not showing this has got an accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Raspbian uses `systemd` to manage services by default, not SysV. Hence `sysv-rc-conf` and `chkconfig` having an inconsistent behaviour.

To disable `nginx` upon boot do:

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx.service
```

As for having `nginx` files hanging around after a successful purge, something must have gone terribly wrong, or there are still packages lying around. The latter is bound to be the case, as nowadays `nginx` is not a single package anymore, and you need to remove several packages:

```
$apt-cache search nginx | grep ^nginx | awk ' { print $1 } '
nginx-common
nginx-doc
nginx-extras
nginx-extras-dbg
nginx-full
nginx-full-dbg
nginx-light
nginx-light-dbg
```

What happened is that `nginx` went from having a single package to multiple ones. You may list the nginx packages you have still installed:

```
dpkg -l  | awk ' { print $2 } '  | grep ^nginx
```

As you updated the post with the `nginx` packages that you still have, I do recommend doing:

```
dpkg --purge nginx-common nginx-full
```

For a future reference, you can check the available packages at:

```
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/nginx
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks :) However, why it keept running after an `apt-get remove`? doesn't `update-rc.d` neither work in raspbian?

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep ^nginx` gives me no output, but removing the exponent character it returns two results (post updated). Is it how should it be?

Comment: oh right, I still having `nginx-common` and `nginx-full` atm, uninstalling... and done, it's actually removed now, thanks again! :)